# Unable to open pickle file in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pickle, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to open a pickle file in colab

```
import pickle 
with open('0.pickle', 'rb') as fid:
     data3 = pickle.load(fid)
```

It gave me an error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'algorithms'
```

I installed it using

```
!pip install algorithms
```

Now it is giving me an error

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-af1bade4658d> in <module>()
      1 import pickle
      2 with open('0.pickle', 'rb') as fid:
----> 3      data3 = pickle.load(fid)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'algorithms.configuration'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

which i am unable to install or figure out the issue

Comment: if you saved pickle with `algorithms.configuration` then you may have to `import` it before load pickle.

Comment: It is a file that i downloaded from internet. and importing algorithms.configuration doesn't work